# convert polygon to svg bezier curve

Tags: d3.js, svg, geojson, topojson

As far as I can tell, there isn't a great answer to this problem, but hoping someone out there might be able to provide some guidance. Polygons rendering in canvas or SVG are fine, but the more granular the data, the more dismal the performance gets. This is especially true when a spline-basis algorithm is applied to polygon to create the illusion of a 'smooth' polygon. A smooth polygon is technically impossible because they are simply lines, so all you can do is add more points to create the this illusion.

**Does anyone know of a way to take a polygon and convert it to bezier curves using a spline basis algorithm?**

Edit:

Essentially I'm looking for what this Corona SDK is doing in this video:

Take a large amount of straight points and converting them to fewer curve points creating a smooth look of the original path (and less data).

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v63NAzQE7Bw

Comment: A degenerate spline/bezier is a straight line so you can convert a polygon to multiple degenerate beziers pretty straightforwardly. I suspect this isn't what you're looking for so if not, perhaps you could make your question clearer.

Comment: @RobertLongson sure thing. Just updated with a video of what I'm looking to do.

Comment: I think you can do this in Inkscape.

Comment: The description of that video includes information on how it was done and where to find the code.  Is there some other problem preventing you from using that?

Comment: What's the use case for this?  With `d3` for example, it would be pretty easy to take tons of data and convert it into a single path.  These paths can become extremely complex without real performance problems.  Play around with this [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/f705fc55e6f26df29354) to see what I mean, it's using a spline fit.